# Angular 5 Component Variable Undefined In Single Page App Without Browser Refresh

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I have a Directive defined in my Angular application that exposes an `@Input()` to be set:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[options]'
})

export class ExampleDirective {

  [...]

  @Input() options:any;

  constructor(private el:ElementRef) {
    System.import('required-js-lib-1.js').then(()=>{
      System.import('required-js-lib-2.js').then(()=>{
        this.attach()
      })
    })
  }

  attach() {
    console.log(this.options); // problem is here
  }
}
```

On components that have an HTML `form` tag, I can use this directive and supply the appropriate options:

`<form id="my-form" [options]="validationOptions">`

In the component's TypeScript (`ts`) file, I define `validationOptions`:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  [...]

  validationOptions: any = { /* Some values here */ }

  [...]

}
```

If I navigate to this page directly, (e.g. `http://localhost:4000/#/Example/`), then everything works as expected. **However, if I click a link within my Single Page Application to navigate to that component, `validationOptions` is undefined within the directive.**

I added some `console.log` statements within the component's constructor and in `ngOnInit`, as well as within the directive itself when it first reads its `options` variable.

- When I go to the component directly in the browser, all three areas show that `validationOptions` / `options` have the value.
- When I navigate to the component from within my Single Page Application, the component constructor and `ngOnInit` show that `validationOptions` has a value, but within the directive, `options` is `undefined`.

How do I make it so that my `validationOptions` variable within my component is always passed to `options` within my directive, regardless of whether or not I visit the component directly versus navigating to it within Single Page Application land?

EDIT: More information. The order of directive/component constructor/init varies based on the two scenarios, which could be related.

**When the component is loaded directly in browser and it works**

```
component.ctor: [object Object]
directive.ctor: undefined
component.init: [object Object]
directive.attach(): [object Object]
```

**When the component is loaded via Single Page App navigation and fails**

```
component.ctor: [object Object]
directive.ctor: undefined
directive.attach(): undefined
component.init: [object Object]
```

The component's `ngOnInit` method is getting called later in the second case (after the directive's constructor/attach() methods are called (attach() being where the value is accessed), which may be the cause of this... But I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try getting the promise response inside `ngOnInit`**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    System.import('required-js-lib-1.js').then(()=>{
      System.import('required-js-lib-2.js').then(()=>{
        this.attach()
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: That did the trick! Knew I was on the right track but am still new to Angular stuff. I had to tack on `implements OnInit` to my directive but that was no big deal. Thanks!